# App crashed when coming from inactive to active state in iPhone

Tags: iphone, cllocationmanager

I am making an application in which have to show user current location on map with some time set, i have worked on that and it is working for me, however if i leave the app open and after 5 minutes app goes to inactive state i stop the location update and after 5 minutes if i again relock the slider and check the app, it comes into active state , have called location update and show the current location, however few times it got crashed from inactive to active state

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [locationManger stopUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    locationManger.delegate = self;
    [locationManger startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only have to show the user's location on the map, then you dont need CLLocationManager. Just use

`mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;`

Comment: but where should i called this, and also would you please tell me that when app is inactive, which method calls first when slider comes

Comment: in viewDidLoad. You can find out for yourself by putting log statements.